# Attachment PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, email-attachments

I'm trying to send some files through a contact form. But, I have two problems.

**First**: the files arrive without format, example: *phpjL9y80*.

**Second**: I don't know if PHPMailer have a function or something like this to filter the extensions, because, I need only .doc, .docx and .pdf files.

Can someone help me, please?

```
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
```

Comment: Show us the code you are using to send the mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your uploaded file somewhere in your server. Then attach it.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"/path/to/directory/". $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

To filter it, maybe PHPMailer doesn't have something to do it.
But, you can use this:

```
$allowedExts = array("doc", "docx", "pdf");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));

if (in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
    $mail->AddAttachment("/path/to/directory/". $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
}
```

To delete that file after sending the email just [unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) it.

```
unlink("/path/to/directory/". $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help Luigi, but one thing. The files can't stay in server (secure reasons). They need be attached in the form, and submitted. Can you help me solve this, please?

Comment: @ArthurMello, unlink (delete) the file after sending the mail. `unlink("/path/to/directory/". $_FILES["file"]["name"]);`

Comment: Some errors: Could not access file: /home/rcom/public_html/project/adv/attach_tmp/test.docx Warning: unlink(/home/rcom/public_html/projetos/adv/attach_tmp/teste.docx) [function.unlink]: No such file or directory in /home/rcom/public_html/project/adv/attach_tmp/test.docx Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/rcom/public_html/project/adv/templates/templatename/wrapper/mail/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php:1370) in /home/rcom/public_html/project/adv/templates/templatename/wrapper/mail/send_mail_client.php on line 75

Comment: @ArthurMello. use a relative path instead.

Comment: Same error Luigi, Could not access file: /attach_tmp/test.docx

Comment: @ArthurMello, Is the file been copied to the server? And is the attachment working?

Comment: No. After click in 'send', shows this error: http://s24.postimg.org/66bvmac39/image.png

Comment: If the file is not moving to that directory maybe because of permissions. Change the folder permissions to 774 just in case.